# Jobs search by country in https://careers.stackoverflow.com does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

When I go to https://careers.stackoverflow.com and apply **Location** filter it shows always **0 jobs**. It works if I search by city, but does not work if I search by country.

Comment: Indeed, searching jobs by country is currently broken. Stand by, we'll look into this shortly. In the meantime, note that you can still search for *companies* by country: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/companies?searchTerm=&location=canada&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles

Answer (score 1):

Ooops; find usages and find all didn't pick up on a usage of this field and so it got removed from the search index.

Fix going out to prod right now. Takes about a minute to rebuild the index.

Thanks for the heads up!